# how to use Logitech Anywhere MX back/forward button on OSX Finder?

Tags: finder, macos

is there a way to use Logitech Anywhere MX's back/forward button on OSX Finder? I can use these buttons on Chrome or any other browsers succesfully, but cannot find a way to do so on Finder?

Comment: should be the same key command... Cmd [ or Cmd ]

Comment: what exactly do you mean? back/forward buttons are already working as they should be on browsers, but not on Finder. How could i find a way to make these buttons work like i use them on browsers?

Comment: so you mean you didn't set them up to be a key command in the first place, they just 'accidentally' work with browsers. I have a different Logitech mouse, btw - mine is set to key commands.

Comment: as i install Logitech's drivers, it comes with predefined back/forward actions. I was hoping it worked in the same way for Finder, but it didn't :(

Comment: I don't actually use Logitech's own CP - their Mac support was very poor when I first moved this mouse over to the Mac. I use [Steermouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) instead, but it's not free.

Comment: apperantly Steermouse can be configured to work on both browsers and Finder. I also found the way of assigning keystrokes on Logitech Control Center. It should work by default as it's indicated though. Btw LCC still doesn't have driver for OSX Yosemite 10.10

Comment: Steer mouse can be set to 'default' or 'per app' for any app you need. I've used it for years, it's very solid. As there was no LCC when i started with this mouse & Mac, I've never used the Logitech one at all

Answer (score 10):

In the Logitech Control Center, change the assigned action for *Thumb Back Button* and *Thumb Forward Button* to Keystrokes instead of Back and Forward.

For *Thumb Back Button*, set the keystroke to **`⌘[`** (`Command-[`) and for *Thumb Forward Button*, set it to **`⌘]`** (`Command-]`).

(This keystroke combination can be seen in the Firefox *Keyboard Shortcuts* page (currently at `Help > Keyboard Shortcuts`), and in the Chrome *Keyboard shortcuts* page as well (`Help > Keyboard shortcuts`).

Comment: Is there no way to do it without Logitech's software?

Comment: You no longer need to set the keystrokes, just setting the buttons to "Back" and "Forward" works in both Finder and browsers. I'm not sure if Logitech's software or macOS has been updated to make this work, but it does. Tested using Catalina and Logitech Gaming Software v9.02.22.

Comment: You can perform the same functionality with BetterTouchTools @Chris - I've just used this answer to assign my old Logitech mouse thumb buttons to the above keystrokes.

Comment: @edanfalls That did not work for me

Comment: It works for me after installing [Logi Options+ Beta](https://www.logitech.com/en-ch/software/logi-options-plus.html) on MacBook Pro M1. And yes, this version runs natively on Apple Silicon ARM Processor.

Answer (score 1):

The Logitech application that worked for me in 2022 on M1 macOS 12.3.1, was [Logi Options](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/software/options.html).

Note that the zip you'll be downloading is options_installer.zip, which unzips to LogiMgr Installer 9.50.122.app, and when installed it appears as Logi Options.app in /Applications...

Unplug and plug in the USB cable connecting the mouse and mac.

Finder, Chrome, Slack, Xcode all started to go back and forward using the side buttons on my mouse (M-U0007).

For Visual Studio Code, https://superuser.com/a/1710037/332630 this answer worked.

BetterTouchTool, Logitech Control Center Installer, didn't work for me.